# Do missions scale difficulty depending on the number of players in your fireteam?

Tags: destiny

In Destiny, does the difficulty of a mission get scaled depending on the number of players in your fire-team?

I'm finding that the story missions are rather easy when I'm under-level and without any additional players, so wondering if having more players will scale accordingly? I believe Diablo III made is harder when more than one player was playing a level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it adds more enemies and makes them slightly harder if you have more people in your team.

Most of the story missions are meant to be beatable fairly easily on Normal, so it sounds like you're having the expected experience.